volcanic metallurgy + blacksmithing
Could you create a void or gap above a lava tunnel/flow that could be used as the heat source for a smelter to create high quality steel i.e., a volcanic open hearth smelter and concurrently use a similar gap to heat steel for forging.
Ignoring the following issues; the gasses that could corrupt the steel making/forging, and the health effect of said gasses to workers.

no lava is far too cold for smelting iron, even the hottest lava is about 500 degrees too cold. if you want somthing from the earth, natural gas seeps have been used in the past as fuel for smelting.

@John please don't answer in comments, write it as an answer

@John: At least some kinds of lava are hotter then ye olde skoole bloomery furnaces (about 1050°C) which were used for smelting iron before the invention of the the blast furnace.

What is "a smelter to create high quality steel"? Steel is not made in smelters. What is an "open hearth smelter"? I know what an open-hearth furnace is; they are used to convert pig iron into steel by burning off the carbon; but there is no smelting involved in that process.

@AlexP Steel is made in smelters (not blast furnaces though), usually very little and in fact in most metal working traditions it's purely accidental, but it is there; it is generally correct to say that smelting doesn't create steel as a finished product. Most people wouldn't know it from looking at a modern steel plant though, once the ore goes in they rarely let the iron get cold enough to differentiate the "pig iron" phase of the production chain.

No, for many reasons
Problem 1 The hottest lava barely reaches the temprature at which you can do the worst kind of smelting. But it does not sustain that heat for long enough to be useful, as soon as you try to use it for heat it drops below that temprature. Lava is not producing heat like somthing being burned it is just hot stuff. No lava is going to stay at a high enough tempratures long enough to be useful for smelting even if you only want crappy wrought iron. No lava is hot enough to make steel.
problem 2 lava is sticky and cools into a solid, so you end up with everything encased in rock. and it will cool on contact, its not like a fuel which generates heat. Of course as soon as lava cools it makes a good insulator so you can't keep the heat flowing. The hottest lava is also ultramafic lava so it only occurs on islands far from continents, so you wont have a source of iron anywhere near it. If you somehow got it hot enough and try to forge said iron you end working the lava into the iron, which  is like some weird kind of reverse smelting.
Problem 3, The hottest lava is also ultramafic lava such volcanoes don't produce lava for long or do so intermittenly or are minor components of larger flows, so you are talking about long distance transport for an unreliable heat source. As soon as it comes out of the ground it is cooling off, and you have no good way to transfer the heat from the lava to the metal. As I said hot lava is sticky liquid emerging under pressure from a moving source, which means it is much much harder to work with than any normal industrial process, since you can't do much to control where it is or build anything lasting to protect from the heat. The uncontrollable unpredictable aspect of lava is one of your largest hurdles.
Upside ultramafic lava has virtually no gasses so at least your not poisoning them, it also will not bother the metalurgy of the iron. But what about a lava tube which will help trap the heat, a lava tunnel hot enough to be even close to useful will kill any human who enters it, contray to movies convection is a thing, and it doesn't solve any of the problems.
If you really want volcanoes involved there are a few extremely rare iron ores produced from volcanoes, or smelt somthing with a far lower melting temprature like lead or gold, which is at least possible even if it makes no sense to do so.
Edit: As Ash mentioned there is no significant erupting ultramafic lava on earth today, so you need to tweek your planet to even make it possible.

Mafic lavas occur on islands, in the modern world true ultramafics are, generally, a thing of the past, (the exception is flood basalts and that's a whole other problem) there has been too much mantle depletion. Some of the current active tubes on Hawaii have been transporting lava from vent to sea for over a decade at this stage so there are situations, though rare, in which you could set up in a reliable location.

Fair enough, in the absence of any information I try to assume "Earth today" and let the OP take what they can from the information I can give them.

@Ash there are ultramafic lavas erupting today but they are minor components of larger eruptions, but yes to get any of quanity you need to go to the past. I'll add some stuff about that.


Lava is molten or partially molten rock (magma) that has been expelled from the interior of a terrestrial planet (such as Earth) or a moon onto its surface. Lava may be erupted at a volcano or through a fracture in the crust, on land or underwater, usually at temperatures from 800 to 1200 °C

(source: Wikipedia)
Iron melts at 1538 °C (source: Wikipedia)
This alone makes the process you have in mind not possible.
Even if you had very hot lava, hot enough to melt iron, you have an additional problem: using coal to melt iron has the additional advantage that it provides "for free" the reducing atmosphere needed to convert iron oxide, which is what you have in iron ore, into an alloy of iron and carbon, which is then further refined into the various kind of steel and other iron alloys.
Only by having high temperature you won't be able to replicate the process happening in a blast furnace.

For literally thousands of years iron was smelted in bloomery furnaces which operated at around 1,000 °C to 1,100 °C. The point is that it is not necessary to melt the iron in order to smelt it from ore. (On the other hand, yes, I don't see how lava would help all that much with smelting iron. Maybe reduce the consumption of charcoal would be worthwhile if charcoal is extremely expensive.)

@alex, the hottest laval does not stay that temprature for very long, not nearly long enough to contribute to smelting. bloomery furnaces need prolonged heating. lava does not stay hot, it does not have an internal source for the heat, as soon as you use it to heat anything it turns solid, so it can't supply heat for very long and then you have the problem of getting everything out of the now solid lava. just barely reaching the temp of a bloom is not good enough it has to sustain it.

@John: Lava lakes do exist and they stay hot for a long time. But all this is irrelevant, because I still don't see how simply having a source of heat would be of significant help with smelting iron. It might be of some help for small amounts of ore. Major help no.

@alex Lava lakes are also way colder than is useful.

Sorry they're a cool fantasy, i.e. possible if given a magical assist, but it can't be done in the real world.
The biggest problem is not heat, that is a major hurdle but the bigger problems are chemical. Smelting is not the process of melting ore down to free the metal, smelting is a chemical process in which a strong reducer, usually direct contact with Carbon (either charcoal or coke) or Carbon Monoxide as a furnace gas, but sometimes Aluminium or another reactive free metal, is used to remove the oxygen from the metal oxide of the processed ore, usually without complete melting. Heat acts as a catalyst and accelerator for this process. A "lava smelter" has no carbon source to create reduction, some lavas do produce carbon monoxide but that is not in isolation nor in situations where the lava is calm enough to encourage building works, and thus won't work for smelting metals.
Sorry just reread the question, ignore this bit.
Additionally lava smelters and forges don't work because practically all lavas, and all the ones that are hot enough, produce sulfurous gases. The addition of sulfur to any alloy I can think of universally causes increased brittleness making them useless for anything but extremely decorative purposes.
Having ignored that then yes you could use a lava heated forging hearth reasonably successfully to work wrought iron and mild steel. For high carbon steels you need more heat than is easily concentrated from a volcanic source, yellow heat or better.
Added note, if we're excluding the possibility of corruption the heat of a lava tube could be quite valuable in the initial ore roasting for improving lower quality ores such as Limonite, Goethite and Siderite driving off water, carbon, and sulfur impurities to save energy during the smelting process.

to play devils advocate you can easily add a reducing agent, and small amounts of sulfur would not be a deal breaker it makes for worse steel but does not actually prevent smelting, sulfur coals were used for a long time, also some ulramafic lavas would actually act to remove sulfur becasue of the high magnesium content.

@John True ultramafic magmas just don't occur anymore, the closest we see is in Hawaii and that's a deep mantle plume, the lava they produce has extremely low thermal capacity, they chill fast when exposed to the air. If you're adding a reducer then you're adding heat, usually quite a lot of it, and you're no longer "smelting with lava", not for my money anyway.

if the lava was the heat source it would stull be smelting, electric arc furnaces exists after all. It doesn't work for iron on any large scale for many practical reasons but you can still smelt with a heat source outside the reducing agent.

@John The action of a chemical reducer is an exothermic reaction. Electric arc furnaces are, usually used for remelting, not smelting, where they are it's called "direct reduction" and the electrical arc acts as the reducer.

thats a good point I had not considered that the arc itself is a reducing agent. Thats what I get for forgetting what reducing actually is.

@John Sorry had that slightly wrong "direct reduction" is the chemical process, arc reduction is a form of electrolytic reduction, serves me right for typing fast this late at night.

As most answers pointed out, this is not really practical.
HOWEVER, I can think of somesolutions that could work for lava-based blacksmithing:

Drill a hole connecting to a lava flow.
Drop a thick walled iron pipe into the lava, so that some of it flows through the pipe.
the pipe will eventually get red hot, but not hot enough to melt.
If you place small bits of steel or iron on top of the pipe, they will eventually become red hot as well.
Hammer the hot bits. Aside from the initial investment, its basically free-energy blacksmithing.

Alternatively, you can redirect the blasts of superheated air from the lava tubes to melt tin, copper or bronze.
Both the iron-pipe idea and the hot-air idea will also help you pre-roast iron ore, pre-heat metal before putting into an ordinary forge, turn wood into charcoal, turn coal into coke, and cook iron in a charcoal bath to carburize it.
